# Boost elasticsearch result by popolarity in Rails with multi models

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, elasticsearch

I have two models (`Post` and `Comment`) that I want to search with elasticsearch. The `Post` model has a field `popolarity` which is an integer that represent the popolarity of the post.

I am using the gem `elasticsearch-model` and now I want to search on `Posts` and `Comments` with one query, this works fine with

```
Elasticsearch::Model.search('search string', [Post, Comment])
```

Now I want to add an option to boost the `Post` elements by it's `popolarity` field like described in [Boosting by Popularity](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/boosting-by-popularity.html#boosting-by-popularity). Is this possible with the Ruby API I tried sth. like

```
Elasticsearch::Model.search('antilope', [Post, Comment], field_value_factor: {field: 'clicks'})
```

but this gives me this error

> ArgumentError: URL parameter 'field_value_factor' is not supported

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to do it by passing a full-fledge [`function-score`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-function-score-query.html) query like this:

```
Elasticsearch::Model.search({
  "query": {
    "function_score": {
      "query": {
        "match": {
          "_all": "antilope"
        }
      },
      "field_value_factor": {
        "field": "clicks"
      }
    }
  }
}, [Post, Comment])
```

Comment: Thanks this works, I also had to add a `clicks` field to my `Comment` model and set the default values to `1` for all `clicks` fields. But now it works. (Also I had to update my elastic search version from 1.0.3 to 1.7.1 to get the `field_value_factor` work.)